# SQL Server: How to format time interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to format time interval like '99d 99h 99m'. Please see the following SQL for example:

```
-- 1501 minutes should be '1d 1h 1m' (= 1 day + 1 hour + 1 minute)
select datediff(mi, '02-21-2012 00:00', '02-22-2012 01:01')
```

My RDBMS is SQL Server 2005. Is there any smart way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CAST(datediff(dd, '02-21-2012 00:00', '02-22-2012 01:01') AS VARCHAR(12))+'d '+
CAST(datediff(hh, '02-21-2012 00:00', '02-22-2012 01:01')%24 AS VARCHAR(2))+'h '+
CAST(datediff(n, '02-21-2012 00:00', '02-22-2012 01:01')%60 AS VARCHAR(2))+'m'
```

If you want to have leading zeros, you have to use `RIGHT` in addition to the `CAST`. I left this out to make the query easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. But the second line should not be 'd ' but 'h '. I tried to edit but could not save because I had to edit 6 chars at least.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [day] = Datediff(dd, st, et),
       [hour] = Datediff(hh, st, et) % 24,
       [minute] = Datediff(n, st, et) % 60
FROM   (SELECT st = CONVERT(DATETIME, '02-21-2012 00:00'),
               et = CONVERT(DATETIME, '02-22-2012 01:01')) tbl
```

I just dont like to input '02-21-2012 00:00' many times..

Answer (score 0):

first get the minutes between the time interval, for which you have to find the interval in 99d 99h 99m  format. i am just hardcoding the mintues, so your query will be:

```
declare @minutes int = 5690

select cast(@minutes/(24*60) as varchar(10))+'d '+cast((@minutes%(24*60))/60 as varchar(10))+'h '+cast((@minutes%(24*60))%60 as varchar(10))+'m'
```